# Cannot ping Windows 7 machine from Linux machines on same LAN

Tags: linux, networking, windows-7, ping

- All firewalls are turned off.
- I have 3 Fedora 20 machines and 1 Windows 7 machine on the same 172.x.x.x LAN.
- They all have static IP addresses and same subnet. (255.255.255.0)
- The Fedora machines can all ping each other.
- The Windows 7 machine can ping all 3 Fedora machines.
- The Fedora machines, however, cannot ping the Windows 7 machine. I get the response: Destination Host Unreachable.
- I ran Wireshark on the Windows machine. ICMP messages show up when pinging from Windows to Fedora, but not the other way around.
- To further complicate matters, all machines also have a second network adapter hooked up to a second 10.x.x.x network. On THIS network, all machines CAN ping each other, Windows to Fedora AND Fedora to Windows. It's just the 172.x network where the Fedora machines cannot ping the Windows machine.

I know
   there are tons of posts out there already for "cannot ping" issues,
   but I haven't been able to find anything that helps with this
   specific scenario. Or when I do, it turns out to have been a firewall
   issue, and there is no firewall running on these machines.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running `traceroute` from the Fedora machines to the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: I have. I get this response: 

traceroute to 172.124.16.39 (172.124.16.39), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  172.124.16.89 (172.124.16.89)  3003.853 ms !H  3003.844 ms !H  3003.833 ms !H

(where the .39 machine is the Windows machine and the .89 machine is the Fedora machine that I am pinging/tracerouting from. And !H in traceroute means unreachable.)

Comment: Are your routes correctly configured on your Fedora boxes ? If your Windows machine doesn't even see the packets, there might be a problem occuring on the configuration of all your Fedora machines...

Comment: What would I check for? netstat -r shows: Destination: 172.124.16.0 Gateway: *, Genmask: 255.255.255.0 Flags: U MSS: 0 Window: 0 irtt: 0 on two of the Fedora machines. On the third one, everything is the same except Gateway: 0.0.0.0 instead of *. On Windows, no default gateway is defined.

Answer (score 2):

On the Windows machines, make sure that the Network Discovery protocol is turned on.  You can doublecheck this by clicking on "Network" in Explorer, and there may be a prompt at the top of the Explorer window that asks you to turn it on.  The reason it may work on the 10.x.x.x network is because it may recognize that network as a Home or Work network, but the 172.x.x.x network as a public network.  The settings are separate for each type of network.

Comment: I checked and Network Discovery protocol is ON for both Home/Work and Public networks. You're right, the 10.x.x.x network is set as a Home/Work network, and the 172.x.x.x network is set as a public network. (continued below)

Comment: I cannot set the 172.x.x.x as a Home/Work network though, the words "Public network" under "Unidentified network" in Network and Sharing Center are just black and not able to be clicked and changed. From what I understand, the default gateway must be defined in the network adapter's TCP/IP settings in order to be able to change this, but the 172.x.x.x network has no default gateway that I can find, all the machines are connected on this network via a Netgear switch, not a router. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try changing this local group policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Link-Layer Topology Discovery -> Both "Turn on Mapper I/O" and "Turn on Responder".  Configure both of these to "Enabled" and "Allow operation while in" all three types of networks.  If that doesn't do it, then I think my line of thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When pinging from Fedora to Windows on the 172.x.x.x network, it's possible that the source IP of the ping packet is getting set to the IP address on the 10.x.x.x network. This may cause the packet to get dropped immediately by Windows since a packet arrived on the 172.x.x.x interface with a source IP that belongs to the subnet on another interface. This can be easily confirmed by tcpdump/wireshark on Fedora.

======== EDIT ========

So we have confirmed that when Fedora (172.124.16.128) pings Windows (172.124.16.39), the destination MAC address is set to `00:00:00:00:00:00`, which is incorrect. The target MAC should be the MAC address of the network interface on Windows that has the IP address of 172.124.16.39 configured on it.

The process of resolving IP to MAC addresses is done by ARP (Address Resolution Protocol), and should happen automatically in the background. To debug why the MAC address isn't getting resolved properly, please clear all ARP cache on Fedora (Google how to clear ARP cache on Linux), start capturing packets, then see what happens with the ARP packets. If you have trouble understanding the packets, you can post them here, and I will take a look.

Comment: I ran Wireshark on Fedora and the "Source" column shows "Billiont_b1:c4:bc". In the details area it says: "Src: Billiont_b1:c4:bc (00:10:60:b1:c4:bc), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff).

Comment: Further down it says: Sender MAC address: Billiont_b1:c4:bc (00:10:60:b1:c4:bc) Sender IP address: 172.124.16.128 (172.124.16.128) Target MAC address: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00) Target IP address: 172.124.16.39 (172.124.16.39)

Comment: @user3618656 So my guess was wrong, but in confirming that my guess was wrong, you found your problem. :) Target MAC address should be set to the MAC address of the Window's interface that has the IP address of 172.124.16.39. I have not edited my answer with this additional information.

Comment: *now*. I have *now* edited my answer.

Comment: Nevermind! Fixed it. Sigh. Classic PEBKAC. Had the Win7 box plugged into the wrong switch.